# CSS opacity won't transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

This transition was working yesterday - on a windows 7 laptop.

I've moved to my computer and it no longer transitions, I've tried the page in Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Chrome canary, Internet Explorer (11) and Edge.

Of the 6 browsers tested 2 - Firefox and IE 11 successfully transitioned, I'm very confused by why this is happening.

```css
#con {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed; /* was absolute of now non existing parent */
    top: 75px;
    left: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}
.class:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div id="con" style="background-image: url(/img)">
  <div id="id" class="class">
  </div>
</div>
```

What is causing this, and why does it work some times?

- I'm surprised I was able to recreate this even after abstracting the code.

EDIT: This is *very* weird... In the snippet editor it doesn't work - like on my website.

However, when previewing on this page it works fine - same situation with others too.

Comment: Works fine for me, Firefox 51.

Comment: Did you see the edit?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn’t really make sense to me… _“In the snippet editor it doesn't work”_, so it apparently doesn’t work here on StackOverflow, but it works for me. _“[…] like on my page”_, so it also doesn’t work in your page. _“but when viewing it it animates properly”_ — so it does work here? It’s not clear where it works for you and where it doesn’t. Just check the console (press F12) to see if there are CSS errors.

Comment: Agree with Xufox : your code seems correct and I see transition in the snippet editor too.

Comment: On the question, when running the snippet it works, as in this page... When editing the question and pressing run, it doesn't.

Comment: There are / were no CSS errors

Comment: FWIW I can reproduce your problem in FF on Windows 8.1: the transition works here in the resulting snippet in the question, but not in the snippet editor.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the duration? 0.3s could be too short if there are other transitions in play, or your GPU is under any other strain. By increasing the duration, you can rule that out.

Comment: I'd tried that before, nothing changed, I also increased the delay, the change from 0 opacity to 1 was instant but the delay increased as expected. So something very weird is happening.

Comment: Anyone know how to approach this?